# How to setup the Clean Blog Jekyll theme by StartBootstrap on GitHub Pages

Tags: ruby, deployment, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I’m having trouble getting Jekyll to work properly on GitHub Pages. When I try to deploy my repository, all I see on the page is `--- layout: home ---` on a white background, and it appears to be ignoring all of the other files in the repository. I have already checked my code and configuration settings, but I’m not sure what could be causing this issue.

Here is a link to my repository: https://github.com/ny000815/yoshiakiblog-jekyll/actions

The repository I cloned is: https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Locally, it works fine. Maybe you have mixed up baseurl and url in your _config.yml file. Try to add the base URL and URL as in the cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your `config.yml` file:

```
baseurl:            "/yoshiakiblog-jekyll"
url:                "https://ny000815.github.io"
```

The `baseurl` follows the format `/REPOSITORY_NAME`.

Make the following changes to your `package.json` file:

```js
    "homepage": "https://ny000815.github.io/yoshiakiblog-jekyll",
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.
I tried it but it doesn't help.
this is the link for it.
https://ny000815.github.io/yoshiakiblog-jekyll/
Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @ny000815 Assuming you followed [these instructions](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll#installation--setup), does the website work fine locally?